# Adobe Photoshop - "path" coordinates and "path stroke" behavior

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, stroke

I have some things I need to verify in using Adobe Photoshop. I am designing a "precise" dimension related image. It was an archimedian spiral. base on a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tatYcybFdCo) I found on YouTube.  I have to be familiar with 2 things, the `path` and the `stroke`.

Please bear with me if the following numbers is correct:

Suppose I create a canvass with at least 10 pixel width,

[image: With coordinates]

then I create a path using `ellipse tool with 1:1 from center with with 7px`.

1. Am I right to assume that this is what happens, the path transverse
   the `x-axis` at `7 px` mark?

[image: Should the path transverse 7px?]

Then I `path stroke` the path I just created with a brush configured to `2px`.

2. Am I right to assume that from 7px, 5px to 9px are all filled? Like
   this?

[image: Filled path stroke 2px]

Are my assumptions and images (2) and (3) correct?

Can somebody please tell me if I'm right?

Comment: This is one of those questions that is easier to test than ask,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Did not watch the video)

Stroked paths always place the stroke on the **center of the path** by default. *Although with vector shapes in Photoshop, it is possible to change that stroke alignment via the stroke options.* But I'll assume everything is set to the defaults.

The measurement for the stroke is not added to *both* sides of the path. It's a **cumulative** figure. A 2px stroke means 1px inside and 1px outside.  Your image (3) would require a 4px stroke -- the total sum of pixels to be covered.

I can't tell where you are getting 7px from in your image. If I extrapolate the rest of the ellipse (red line below), the measurement scale seems to have no logical basis for its placement.

[image]

In this case, the ellipse based on your posted screenshot is 226px in width. So a 2px stroke would increase the width to 228px - adding 1px to the left and right sides. As well as reducing the diameter to 224px - subtracting 1px from the inner dimensions.